# textfields ignore min-width when in a table... any workaround?

Tags: google-chrome, css, safari, webkit

in google chrome on windows,

```
<input type="text" style="min-width:10px;width:100%;">
```

as you see here works:

```
<div style="width:50px;background:red;">
    <input type="text" style="min-width:10px;width:100%;">
</div>
```

here not!

```
<table style="background:red;">
    <tr><td><input type="text" style="min-width:10px;width:100%;"></td></tr>
</table>
```

i'm looking for a pure css solution (size="1" resolves my problem, btw)

Comment: What's not working ? http://jsbin.com/ejekix/edit#html,live

Comment: Do you mean max-width or is it min-width? Whats the requirement? Min-width rules are correctly followed even in the table..

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ejekix/4 i want to fix this behavior, why input and div render differently?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
cellpadding="0" 

cellspacing="0"
```

to your table like

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background:red;">
    <tr><td><input type="text" style="min-width:10px;width:100%;"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome and Safari simply do not support the min-width property on table elements. They will, however, respect min-width when applied to table cells.

Other:

1. Firefox: Supported (tested in 5, not sure since which version)
2. Internet Explorer: Supported (since IE8. IE7 and below do not seem
   to support it) Chrome: Not supported (all versions as far as I can
   tell) Safari: Not supported (all versions as far as I can tell
3. Opera: Supported (tested in 11.5, not sure since which version)

Check this site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/min-width

maybe try some %...